# Large value of $X\beta$ in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, lasso, regularization

In  logistic regression, the probability is obtained from
$$
Pr = \frac{\exp(X\beta)}{1 + \exp(X\beta)} ~~~~ (1)
$$
From the plot below, it is obvious that if $X\beta$ > 10, the probability approaches 1
[image]
In my case (a penalized logistic regression, details are omitted), my estimate for $\beta$ (and therefore $X\beta$) is very large, > 2000, when plugging the equation (1), R gives out `Inf`.

(Updated details based on @whuber comments: I actually also have some negative values, say, <-2000, so the alternative Equation (2) is not working)
$$
Pr = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-X\beta)} ~~~~~~~(2)
$$

I am looking for some suggestions on how to deal with this situation, where the output is $Pr$.

Possible two approaches I can think of are:

- Use the `if`-condition: If $X\beta$ > 10, then Pr = 1; to compute the probability and skip the equation (1).
- Check my code on the estimation of $\beta$. (though I do not think my code has bugs)
- (based on @whuber's comments) If $X\beta$ is positive, use Equation (2); if $X\beta$ is negative, use Equation (1).
- (based on @BenBolker's comments) Use the R function plogis() to compute the $Pr$, which is the logistic of $X\beta$. The code is `plogis(c(-2000,2000), lower.tail=TRUE)`. A related article is [here](https://ro-che.info/articles/2018-08-11-logit-logistic-r).

Comment: it seems you know what to do already

Comment: Why not just compute the algebraically equivalent $\frac{1}{1+\exp(-X\beta)}$? When $X\beta \gg 0,$ floating point arithmetic will automatically round the result to $1.$

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the quick response. I updated the question based on the comment. Basically, I also have $X\beta << 0$, so I come up with the third approach in the post.

Comment: @Aksakal Thanks for the quick response. I hope so, but still curious if there are other clever approaches

Comment: You could just report your result as the log odds (or, logit of the probability) and avoid computing the exponential altogether

Comment: I'm surprised that you say this is a *penalized* logistic regression. That matters, because one of the purposes of penalized regression is exactly to avoid this situation; it's what I would have recommended if you hadn't said that you were already using it (search on CV, and elsewhere, for "complete separation").  Are you using Firth/bias-reduced algorithm, or ridge/lasso, or ... ? The details could be useful.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the quick response. I tried the function plogis, it is useful and working well.

Comment: @BenBolker It is not a Firth/bias-reduced algorithm, ridge, or lasso, just a customized penalty. However, I think it is an interesting conversation on using the penalized regression to avoid the situation. I was wondering if you have any argument or reference to support that statement using the penalized term could avoid the situation. If so, it is may necessary to update my penalty because it is a surprise to me that my estimated $X\beta$ had such a situation.

Comment: @MossMurderer Thanks for the quick response, I forgot to mention that output is the probability $Pr$.

Comment: I suggested that you look around for discussions of *complete separation*; almost any such discussion will discuss the use of penalties (especially Firth/bias-reduction) to push large values of $\beta$ toward zero.

Comment: @BenBolker Got it. I think I will use your comments as the answer. Do you mind copying your comments as an answer? Then I will accept that answer. Thanks again for your directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the built-in `plogis()` function (which returns the cumulative distribution function of the logistic distribution, which by definition is the same as the logistic/inverse-logit function) it will take care of your computational issues:

```
plogis(c(-2000,2000))
## 0 1
```

Even better, you can get a more precise answer by asking R to provide $\ln(\textrm{logistic}(X\beta))$ directly:

```
plogis(-2000,log.p=TRUE)
## -2000
```

In this case, because the logistic is approximately equal to the exponential function at its lower extent, $\ln(\textrm{logistic}(x)) \approx \ln(\exp(x)) = x$. If you want to convert this to base 10, $-2000/\ln(10)=-868.589$ tells you that $p \approx 10^{-868}$.

Since the logistic function is symmetric, the upper end works similarly: to compute $\ln(1-\textrm{logistic}(x))$, use

```
plogis(2000,log.p=TRUE,lower.tail=FALSE)
## -2000
```

So (as we could have figured out from symmetry), $\textrm{logistic}(2000) \approx 1-10^{-868}$.